# highcharts hover with negativeColor property gives wrong color

Tags: highcharts

I have a series that I'm plotting as type 'column' and it can be both negative or postive.  I want the positive to be green and the negative to be red so I added the following function.

```
function redrawColumns(chart){
        $(chart.series[0].data).each(function(i,e){
            if (e.y < 0 ){
                e.graphic.attr({fill:'rgba(128,0,0,1)'});
            }

        });
```

right above my chart declaration

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {

            renderTo: 'container',
        alignTicks: false,
        events: {
        ....
```

with the original series declared later on in the usual format

```
series: [
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Sentiment',
            data: senti,        
            pointWidth: .3,
            //color: 'green',
            color: 'rgba(34,139,34,1)',
            threshold: 0,
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
```

I have an option such that whenever I scroll over any part of the bar graph, it displays the value but the problem is any bar that I scroll over turns to green and stays green.  How can I make sure the hovering doesn't change the color, ie persists through any kind of mouse movement.  Maybe I should move that function? Also this is being refreshed and plotted once a minute based on data dump to a text file.

Here is my marker, don't think this makes any difference.

```
//marker hover option for the sentiment chart
     column: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            location.href = 'https://www.randomsite.com';
                        }
                    }
                },

                states: {
                    hover: {
            enabled: true,
                        lineWidth: .6,
                        halo: {
                            size: 2,
                            attributes: {
                                fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                                'stroke-width': 1,
                                stroke: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't (*don't have to)* specify a function for negative values.

Rather tackle the problem by using Highchart's [**negativeColor**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.negativeColor) property:

```
series: [
            type: 'column',
            color: 'rgba(34,139,34,1)',
            negativeColor: 'rgba(128,0,0,1)',
            ...
```

For reference, take a look at [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-negative-color/) from highchart's demo examples.

Now we still have the problem with the hovering color. This is [**a known bug**](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2400).

But this bug was solved on [5 December 2014](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/82f63d19eb78a9b6f7febe88f9d1d1df8d1da4c8). So if you use the latest version of Highcharts, it should work.